# Combine jquery variables into one selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm looking for a way to combine jquery variables. Looking through related questions, nobody seems to be trying what I want to do.

`$("body, div, p")` is one method of combining by selectors, but after you assign a selector to a variable, how do you combine them in a similar fashion?

Here is one method I tried, but did not get it to work. I also tried putting them into an array (by simply adding brackets before $body and after $p).

```
$body = $("body");
$div = $("div");
$p = $("p");
$mixed = $($body, $div, $p);
// $mixed = $("body, div, p"); is NOT what I am looking for
```

In my actual script I've got some `<select>` inputs assigned to variables. I would like to put them into groups, so say I have a `<select>` which has "FRUIT" and another one that has "VEGETABLES", I could put them both into a jquery variable called "PRODUCE". Then if I need to perform anything on both of the two, I use produce instead.

...This might just be a stupid way to do things, though.

Comment: Whhy don't you use `$("select")` since both your elements are selects?

Comment: This might just be a stupid way to do things, indeed... **=)**

Comment: I want to cherry-pick the ones that should be grouped together. I suppose this could be done with giving them all ID's, but since they are added programatically I would prefer adding them without using any attributes.

Comment: Why not select them with on selector? selecting them three times and then combine the result is awkward and silly. `$mixed = $("body, div, p");` looks just fine, no need to "improve it". Good Luck.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I think you haven't read my reasoning for why I am not doing. "since they are added programatically I would prefer adding them without using any attributes". Still a dumb way to do it though.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)?

```
$mixed = $body.add($div).add($p);
```

Comment: You've got to be kidding me. I've looked for this for so long... I didn't think it existed.

I never thought of looking for the term "add", though. ("Combine" isn't even found on the page, fml)

Comment: It's good to know that this function exist, but I can't think on a scenario where it's needed. Good Answer!

Comment: Note: don't expect any kind of ordering to be preserved. I tried using this to get the first item that wasn't null by adding two groups together, but it made no difference to the result as to the order I added them

Answer (score 2):

For me, it works fine in jQuery 1.10.2 to simply combine the elements in an array literal before passing into the jQuery constructor: `$mixed = $([$body, $div, $p]);`

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for something like this. In my case I had some objects passed into a common function and some created in memory and I wanted to apply the same click event to all of the objects. In the end I went with James's add solution above but thought I would share another option.

If you put the objects into an array you can use the each iterator to perform an action on them.

```
[$body, $div, $p].each(function(i,e) { e.DoSomething(); });
```

This syntax is longer and you don't get a reusable $mixed object, but there may be some scenarios where this is useful.