# How can I combine jquery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery object that is an array of different tab links: `var $links = $('.tab-link');`

I can use this with `.click` like so: `$links.click()`.

How can I combine this with another selector, like `$('.btn-next')`?

`$('.btn-next '+ $links).click()` and `$('.btn-next', $links).click()` both result in:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .btn-next [object Object]

Comment: would that other selector get some other callback function in the `.click()`?

Comment: Use `.add()` - I'll see if I can dig out where's it's been asked before

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine jquery variables into one selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056648/combine-jquery-variables-into-one-selector)  (wasn't the one I was thinking of though, so there are others)

Comment: `$('.btn-next', $links)` is the same as `$links.find(".btn-next")` so would work if you were trying to get the equivalent of `$(".tab-link,.tab-link .btn-next")`.   `[object Object]` is because you're combining a string with an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with `filter()` to attach the `click()` event to all elements that have the classes `tab-link` and `btn-next`:

```
 $links.filter(".btn-next").click(function(){});
```

And in case you want to attach the `click()` event to separate elements with the class `tab-links` or `btn-next`, it's

```
 $($links, ".btn-next").click(function(){});
```

Comment: FTY: last one doesn't look right (possibly) should be: `$(".btn-next", $links)` but that doesn't match your text.  `$("selector", "selector")` isn't valid for "or"

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for your feedback, I have it corrected.