# jQuery combine all variables together into one

Tags: jquery, arrays, show

I have this piece of code here and I am trying to combine it together to be more semantic.

```
$(jsSearchPageNr[pageNo]).show();
$(jsSearchPageNr[pageNo - 2]).show();
$(jsSearchPageNr[pageNo - 1]).show();
```

What I am trying to do is something like this

```
$(jsSearchPageNr[pageNo - 1], jsSearchPageNr[pageNo - 2], jsSearchPageNr[pageNo]).show();
```

I have also tried this

```
 $([jsSearchPageNr[pageNo - 1], jsSearchPageNr[pageNo - 2], jsSearchPageNr[pageNo]]).show();
```

jsSearchPageNr variable looks like this

```
var jsSearchPageNr = $('.search-results-wrapper__pagination--' + className + ' .js-search-page-number');
```

but this gives me an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Cheers!

Comment: It would help if we could see what jsSearchPageNr looks like

Comment: Thx I edited my question. @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: As `jsSearchPageNr` = `$(...)` you don't need to rewrap it `$(jsPgNr)` just `jsPgNr.eq(pageNo).show()`.   It looks like the `undefined style` issue is because there aren't jsPgNr items with those indexes.

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323969/2181514) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056661/2181514), you can combine jquery collections using `.add()`:  using your original [i] code: `$(jsSearchPageNr[pageNo - 1]).add(jsSearchPageNr[pageNo - 2]).add(jsSearchPageNr[pageNo]).show();` should do the trick.